# How can I create a live notification of a web event?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

so I'm looking to play a .wav file on my server when a user signs up on my website.

I'm essentially trying to create a live listening php file (or whatever I need to make) that is triggered by a website (I use Wordpress) user being created that plays a .wav file.

I've looked everywhere... php is server side so I'm assuming it can't play a .wav sound on my computer (client side?).  I've tried javascript methods with no luck.

How do you make a "Gmail style email notification."  When I get an email, gmail pops up a little notify alert box on my screen.  If I can get my php event triggered file to open a new popup, I could have that play the sound on the browser popup and then close right after.

Any ideas?  Web sockets maybe?  I've heard of those...

Comment: You can use the Wordpress `user_register` event hook to start this process, but you would need an open connection from your server to your local computer to do this.  I couldn't tell you how to handle that end of it, but it sounds like a security nightmare. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register  I think you'd be better off just configuring wordpress to email you when new users register, and then configuring your email notifications to play the  sound.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid of the security issues too as I have no idea what I'm doing really...

Setting up an email notification should be easy enough, thanks dawg.